# Send email to validate email address while user creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership-provider, email-validation

I have an asp.net site where I am using a XML based Tiny Membership provider. I want to send an email on email address provided by user while he creates an account on my site, which will have link. Its only after clicking on this link I want his account to get activated. How can incorporate this functionality in existing default behavior of Membership Provider?

Answer (score 3):

When you create the user, set `MembershipUser.IsApproved` to false, and send an email with the link to the new user.  The `Membership.CreateUser` method has a parameter `isApproved` for this purpose.

When the user clicks on the link, validate then set `MembershipUser.IsApproved` to true.